# infinite loop when selected programmatically a cell

Tags: swift, loops, tableview

I have a tableview with a textfield in every row.
I need to reload the tableview and programmatically select the row the user had selected.
The user can write what he wants. The data will be deleted when the textfield's editing has ended and added when the textfield has begun editing.

But I get a infinite loop. Please cloud you help me?

**My code :**

```
import UIKit

class OptionsItemViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate, UITextFieldDelegate {

    let context = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer.viewContext
    var textFiedlDelegate: UITextField? = nil
    var categorySelected: Category?
    var options: [String] = []
    var nameOptions: [String] = []
    var cellSelected: Int = 0
    var viewHeight: CGFloat = 0
    var selectedRow: IndexPath? = nil
    var tableviewNeedToReload: Bool = false

    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
    @IBOutlet weak var keyboardAlwaysShow: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var newFeatureButton: UIBarButtonItem!

    private let db = DataBase()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.tableView.dataSource = self
        self.textFiedlDelegate?.delegate = self
        self.title = categorySelected!.name
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardWillShow), name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillShow, object: nil)
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardWillHide), name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillHide, object: nil)
    }

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)

        db.getItemOptions(predicateFormat: "id == \(self.categorySelected!.id)", completion: { results in
            self.categorySelected = results.first!
            self.options = self.categorySelected!.options as! [String]
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.tableView.reloadData()
            }
        })
    }

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(false)
        self.viewHeight = self.view.frame.size.height
    }

    override func viewDidDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidDisappear(false)
        var index = 0
        while index < self.options.count {
            if self.options[index] != "" {
                index += 1
            } else {
                self.options.remove(at: index)
            }
            db.setCategoryOptions(category: self.categorySelected!, options: self.options, index: cellSelected)
        }
    }

    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        self.view.endEditing(true)
    }

    @IBAction func newFeature(_ sender: Any) {
        if self.options.last != "" {
            let indexPath: IndexPath = IndexPath(row: self.options.count, section: 0)
            self.options.append("")
            self.tableView.reloadData()

            let cell = tableView(self.tableView, cellForRowAt: indexPath) as! CellItemOptions
            cell.nameOptionsItem.becomeFirstResponder()
        }
    }

    // MARK: - TableView Functions

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return options.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let option = options[indexPath.row]
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: CellItemOptions.identifier, for: indexPath) as! CellItemOptions
        cell.nameOptionsItem.delegate = self
        cell.configureCell(with: option)
        return cell
}

    func textFieldDidBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
        self.cellSelected = options.index(of: textField.text!)!
        let indexPath: IndexPath = IndexPath(row: self.cellSelected, section: 0)
        self.tableView.reloadData()
        let cell = self.tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as! CellItemOptions
        cell.nameOptionsItem.becomeFirstResponder()
    }

    func textFieldDidEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
        if textField.text! == "" {
            if self.options[cellSelected] != "" {
                db.setRemoveDetailsItem(category: self.categorySelected!, index: cellSelected)
            }
            self.options.remove(at: cellSelected)
        } else {
            self.options[cellSelected] = "\(textField.text!)"
            db.setAddDetailsItem(category: self.categorySelected!, index: cellSelected)
        }
        db.setCategoryOptions(category: self.categorySelected!, options: self.options, index: cellSelected)
    }

    // MARK: - Keyboard

    func keyboardWillShow(_ notification: NSNotification) {
        if let keyboardSize = (notification.userInfo?[UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.cgRectValue {
            if self.view.frame.size.height == self.viewHeight {
                self.view.frame.size.height -= keyboardSize.height
            }
        }
    }

    func keyboardWillHide(_ notification: NSNotification) {
        if let keyboardSize = (notification.userInfo?[UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.cgRectValue {
            if self.view.frame.origin.y != self.viewHeight {
                self.view.frame.size.height += keyboardSize.height
            }
        }
    }
}

class CellItemOptions: UITableViewCell {
    static let identifier = "OptionsItemCell"

    @IBOutlet weak var nameOptionsItem: UITextField!

    private let tableView = OptionsItemViewController()

    func configureCell(with cell: String) {
        nameOptionsItem.text = cell
    }
}
```

**EDIT :**

The loop is due to the reload data...
Like I reload data in `textFieldDidBeginEditing()`, the view is reloaded more and more ... And I need to `textFieldDidBeginEditing()` to know the row selected by the user.

Comment: Which one is the function that gets looped? Can you post your stack trace?